# What is the default location for certificates created using "dotnet dev-certs https"

Tags: windows, .net-core

Following dot net core CLI command allows one to create a certificate.

*dotnet dev-certs https*

This command has an optional parameter for specifying an export path. Does anyone know where the certificate goes if this path is not specified?

It seems like the help output of the command: dotnet dev-certs --help does not seem to contain this information and I have not been able to locate much details on this at other sources either.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like by default it goes into the current user's (logged on user's) personal certificate store:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This is not a good answer. What about Linux?

Comment: Very good point! In this case perhaps the question should have been more specific. May be we can take the opportunity to expand on that missing aspect in this answer :).

Comment: Where is the file location of these certificates?

Comment: It's not a good answer for Windows either, how do I access these files?

Answer (score 11):

On linux it defaults to `~/.dotnet/corefx/cryptography/x509stores/my/` (using dotnet 5)

Comment: 3.1 uses the same location, fyi